# Entity Famework creates columns from objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-migrations

I'm facing an issue when I'm trying to create reations between my users. One user can be a dietician for another, so I have this structure:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
        [ForeignKey("MenteeId")]
        public virtual ICollection<MenteesDieticians> Dieticians { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("DieticianId")]
        public virtual ICollection<MenteesDieticians> DieticianMentees { get; set; }
}

public class MenteesDieticians
{
        [Key]
        public int MenteesDieticiansId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [ForeignKey("Mentee")]
        public string MenteeId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("MenteeId")]
        public virtual ApplicationUser Mentee { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [ForeignKey("Dietician")]
        public string DieticianId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("DieticianId")]
        public virtual ApplicationUser Dietician { get; set; }
}
```

Also in my DbContext class I'm defining relations:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
            .HasMany(x => x.DieticianMentees)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.DieticianId);
        builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
            .HasMany(x => x.Dieticians)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.MenteeId);

        builder.Entity<MenteesDieticians>()
            .HasOne(x => x.Mentee)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey<MenteesDieticians>(t => t.MenteeId);
        builder.Entity<MenteesDieticians>()
            .HasOne(x => x.Dietician)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey<MenteesDieticians>(t => t.DieticianId);
}
```

Finally, my migration code looks like this:

```
    migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
        name: "MenteesDieticians",
        columns: table => new
        {
            MenteesDieticiansId = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                .Annotation("MySQL:ValueGenerationStrategy", MySQLValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
            MenteeId = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
            DieticianId = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
            ApplicationUserId = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
            ApplicationUserId1 = table.Column<string>(nullable: true)
        },
```

Why do I have those ApplicationUserId and ApplicationUserId1 columns? How to fix that?

What do you think about defining those relations like this? To be honest I need the user to have only one dietician, but I didn't find a way to implement it.

Comment: I would start by going into you database and fix issues.  Then refresh the paaping which should fix issues.  I suspect you have some keys in the database and when the ,mapping was creates the mapping didn't know how to resolve the duplicate key names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following configuration. First, it's enough to configure from one side only. And second, remove the annotations from the model.

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
        .HasMany(x => x.Dieticians)
        .WithOne(x => x.Dietician)
        .HasForeignKey(x => x.DieticianId);
    builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
        .HasMany(x => x.DieticianMentees)
        .WithOne(x => x.Mentee)
        .HasForeignKey(x => x.MenteeId);
}
```

I have to say, you have a bit weird setup here. Can you elaborate exactly what's your goal here?

Comment: Wow it works, thank you, after applying this configurations I dont' have those additional columns anymore.
My goal is to create relations between users, to allow them to have another users as dieticians.

Comment: Great, just be careful what you're mapping to what. In the configuration I mapped `Dieticians` to `DieticianID`, and `DieticianMentees` to `MenteeId`. Cross-check if that's what you want. Don't forget to vote the answer too :)